# How to generate a random vector of distribution N(0, sigma^2 * Identity matrix (dxd)) in matlab

Tags: matlab, random, vector

I want to generate a random vector in MATLAB with the distribution `N(0,σ^2*I_dxd)`
d (dimension) can be any number . How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the variance/covariance matrix is `σ^2*I`, then the normals are independent.  Generate `d` independent `N(0,σ^2)`, or `d` standard normals and multiply them by `σ`.

Answer (score 0):

The command you need is `randn` so if you type `help randn` you should be able to figure it out.

Assuming your `I` is zero outside the diagonal:

```
randn(length(σ^2*I_dxd),1).*diag(σ^2*I_dxd)
```

If `I` is not zero outside the diagonal it gets a bit more complex.

Comment: "Assuming your I is zero outside the diagonal" -- the title says Identity matrix so I think it's safe to assume this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `randn(d,1) * sigma` where [`randn()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randn.html) and `sigma` is the standard deviation σ in your problem statement.

You're just talking about the generation of `d` independent identically distributed random variables each with a normal distribution, right?

Comment: yes...I want to generate a random vector of dimension d with mean 0 and variance =sigma^2*I_dxd